# how to get the index value in dictionary using swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

As I am new to swift programming language .I am using the dictionary of two items now i need to take the index path of particular dictionary value .I am using the following code

```
var dictionaryitems = ["computer":"something to make work easy","pen":"used for writing something"]
print(dictionaryitems["pen"])
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit, why you need indexPath ??? if you are using tableView then use array instead of dictionary.

Comment: No i am not using the table view .I need the indexpath for some other calculation

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition. It's **key** based rather than *index* based.

Answer (score 1):

Use firstIndex for this

```
 let index = dictionaryitems.firstIndex(where: {$0.key == "pen"})
```

Comment: i am getting the following error "Value of type '[String : String]' has no member 'firstIndex' "

Comment: Sorry, it looks like this is only available in the latest version of swift

Answer (score 1):

you can get index of key or value by

```
let index = Array(Dictionary.keys).index(of: key/value)
```

by this you will get an optional value which you can unwrap using if-let or guard statement for further use

Answer (score 1):

```
var dictionaryitems = ["computer":"something to make work easy","pen":"used for writing something"]

if let index = dictionaryitems.index(forKey: "pen")  {
    print(dictionaryitems[index].key, ":", dictionaryitems[index].value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you can get the index of a dictionary using swift >

```
if let index = carDataArray?.index(where: {$0["carName"] as! String == "BMW"}) {
            print("Car Found")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerated() for this:

```
for (index, key_value) in dictionaryitems.enumerated(){
    print("\(index) : \(key_value)")
}
```

Output:

> 0 : (key: "pen", value: "used for writing something")
> 1 : (key: "computer", value: "something to make work easy")

so it will easy to understand.

Comment: Keep in mind that the resulting index can change. Add a new key/value to the dictionary and that `for` loop will most likely give different index numbers for each key/value pair. This is not a useful solution in most cases.

Comment: i got it , yes it is not the right solution i think because  dictionary is based on key-value pair and doesn't care about the index like an array, thanks for the clarification.